# Misplaced position of value counts on top of bar graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, nan

I calculated missing values in my dataframe using the code:

```py
per_B = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100
```

And plotted using the following code with NaN value count on top, but the last two value count position is misplaced.

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))
for i,item in enumerate(zip(per_B.keys(), per_B.values)):
    if (item[1] > 0):
        ax.bar(item[0], item[1], label = item[0])
        ax.text(i - 0.40, item[1] + 0.5 , str(np.round(item[1],2)))    
ax.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax.set_xticks([]) 
plt.title('NaN Value percentage in Training Set B')
plt.ylim(0,115)
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.xlabel('Columns')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: NaN value count]

Can someone help me with what went wrong in the code, as the last two column value counts are misplaced?

Comment: As a way to debug, is there a one-to-one correspondence between the index value and the label value? `print(i)` and `print(np.round(item[1],2))`

Comment: Yes, but Idk why the last 2 labels are misplaced? Or if you know some other way (code) to plot the NaN percentage as a bar graph? That would be great...

Comment: And of course, with the value count on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the text is misplaced, is that you let `i` increment even when you don't plot a bar (there seem to be two "items" with `item[1] <= 0` just before the end). You could solve this by placing `i` outside the `for` and incrementing it only when a bar is drawn.

So, something like:

```py
i = 0
for key, value in zip(per_B.keys(), per_B.values)):
    if (value > 0):
        ax.bar(key, value, label=key)
        ax.text(i, value + 0.5, str(np.round(value, 2)), ha='center')
        i = i + 1 # increment the counter
```

The code could be simplified using the [`bar_label()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) function (new in matplotlib 3.4), and also by creating a subset of `per_B` that only contains the nonzero elements:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first create some test data
data = np.random.rand(1000)
data[np.random.randint(0, 1000, 2000)] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1, 10), columns=[*'abcdefghij'])
df['g'] = 1 # no NaNs in columns 'g' and 'h'
df['h'] = 1

per_B = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100

per_B_nonzeo = per_B[per_B > 0] # subset containing all the nonzero vlaues

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, value in per_B_nonzeo.iteritems():
    bar = ax.bar(key, value, label=key)
    ax.bar_label(bar, labels=[f'{value:.2f}'])
plt.show()
```

[image: labeling nonzero bars]

Comment: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'`

Comment: @Huzaifa You'd need to upgrade matplotlib as `bar_label` is new since version 3.4. For older matplotlib versions, you can still use the code in the first part of the post.

Comment: Alright. I am using Jupyter Lab on AWS and I when I tried to update the matplotlib, it said the latest version is installed, but that's the older version.